# Repeating function in Python turtle

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment for school and want to draw a large building with repeating windows. I now you would probably use a for loop for the windows to repeat, but I don't know how to set it up. Any help would be great! Here is my code:

```html
import turtle

def draw_rectangle(t, x, y, width, height, tilt, pen, fill):
    t.hideturtle()
    t.up()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.setheading(0 + tilt)
    t.fillcolor(fill)
    t.pencolor(pen)
    
    t.down()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.forward(width)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(width)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.end_fill()
    t.up()
    
    t.down()
    t.begin_fill()
    draw_rectangle(t, -80, 100, 20, 30, 0, "white", "white")
    t.end_fill()
    t.up()
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me this programming technique” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Well, are you able to write a for loop at all? Can you think of a rule that tells you how many rectangles to draw, and how to determine their positions? What exactly is the difficulty here?

Comment: This is a little outside of the scope of SO, so you might have this question downvoted, but here's a link to learn more about for loops: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: @ Prune I’m really new to programming in general. I just asked a question about this because I’ve tried to set up a for loop for this already but nothing I’m doing is working right. So that’s why I’m here.

Comment: Again, please read the posting guidelines.  Your most recent comment reinforces that your question is off topic.  This is not a tutorial service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By making the window for loop into a function, it will be much easier to call and won't be as long. Declare this function outside of the draw_rectangle function and call it inside the draw_rectangle function with draw_window() whenever you need to draw a window.

```
def draw_window():
    for i in range (2):
        t.forward(width)
        t.left(90)
        t.forward(height)
        t.left(90)
```

Comment: This does not address the stated problem -- which is out of scope for Stack Overflow, anyway.

Comment: Doesn't it show how to turn the code into a for loop?

Comment: The question is for multiple windows.  All you've done is to roll up the code for a single window.

Comment: @Prune I fixed my code so it appropriately answered the question. I apologise for my previous response.

Comment: @ParkSun I'm glad I could help! Could you click the check next to my answer so others know that the problem is resolved? Thanks! :)